# asp.net for finding how long a user spend in a website

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to find how long a user spend in a website . It is to find the time span a user send in a website.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1 (recommended): Get [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/), installation is easy and it gives you some excellent reporting facilities.

Option 2 (harder): Inspect your IIS logs.  You can download software to make it easier to read/understand.